# Unable to load asset

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

this is my pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:


  assets:
  - assets/m1.jpg
  - assets/m2.jpg
  - assets/m3.jpg
  - assets/m4.jpg
  - assets/cat/m13.jpg
```

above images are working except this image

```
         - assets/cat/m13.jpg
```

I'm not getting errors in pubspec.yaml file, and running "flutter packages get" gives an exit code of 0.

In HorizontalListView.dart I having following class

```
                  class _HorizontalListViewState extends State<HorizontalListView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80.0,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Category(
            image_location: " assets/cat/m13.jpg",
            image_caption: "shirts",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error I facing is

```
                    The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (17029): Unable to load asset:  assets/cat/m13.jpg
I/flutter (17029):
I/flutter (17029): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (17029): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter (17029): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (17029): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:484:44)
I/flutter (17029): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:469:14)
I/flutter (17029): #3      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
I/flutter (17029): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
I/flutter (17029): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:325:84)
I/flutter (17029): (elided 13 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (17029):
I/flutter (17029): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: " assets/cat/m13.jpg")
I/flutter (17029): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#5adcb(), name: " assets/cat/m13.jpg",
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

incorrect

```
 assets:
 - assets/m1.jpg
 - assets/m2.jpg
 - assets/m3.jpg
 - assets/m4.jpg
 - assets/cat/m13.jpg
```

correct

```
assets:
  - assets/m1.jpg
  - assets/m2.jpg
  - assets/m3.jpg
  - assets/m4.jpg
  - assets/cat/m13.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the name of the folder,image file name and image extension properly .I believe if all other images are loaded except one.
then

incorrect:

assets:

- assets/m1.jpg
- assets/m2.jpg
- assets/m3.jpg
- assets/m4.jpg
- assets/cat/m13.jpg

correct:

assets:

- assets/m1.jpg
- assets/m2.jpg
- assets/m3.jpg
- assets/m4.jpg
- assets/validFolderName/validImageName.validExtension

for ex: assets/cats/m13.jpg Or assets/cat/m134.jpg Or assets/cat/m13.png

Answer (score 0):

your asset implementation on .yaml file is fail. should be like below

```
  assets:
     - assets/fuse.png
     - assets/not_found.png
```

or to implement all files in the folder;

```
  assets:
     - assets/
```

Comment: you may forgot to add one-tab space

Comment: but in my case, it got executed successfully and also tried with the one you suggested but it getting an error @Murat Aslan